# how to break the lines coming as a output of the grep C1

Tags: bash, shell, loops, grep

-----my input file  [file name -- test]

```
    centos is my bro
    red hat is my course
    ubuntu is my OS
    fqdn is stupid 

    tom outsmart jerry   
    red hat is 3
    red hat is friend
    red hat is my boy
    jerry is small
```

---- my code

```
#! /bin/bash

grep -C1   --color=always "red hat" test
```

--- expected output

```
 centos is my bro
 red hat is my course
 ubuntu is my OS     
 --
 tom outsmart jerry   
 red hat is 3
 red hat is friend
 --
 red hat is 3
 red hat is friend
 red hat is my boy
 --
 red hat is friend
 red hat is my boy
 jerry is small
```

---- coming OUTPUT

```
    centos is my bro
    red hat is my course
    ubuntu is my OS
    --
    tom outsmart jerry   
    red hat is 3
    red hat is friend
    red hat is my boy
    jerry is small
```

---- please provide the necessary option for the grep command   to get the expected output

----- if there is some other way to achieve this output

----- please give reference and the comments in the code

Comment: I do not think there is such option. Write it yourself, in `awk` should be simple.

Comment: yep, grep doesn't have an option to do this, at least on the implementations I've used so far..

Comment: I already showed you how to do that in your previous question, https://stackoverflow.com/q/63416009/1745001

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can i loop through the coming frequency of the keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63416009/how-can-i-loop-through-the-coming-frequency-of-the-keyword)

Comment: @Ed Morton i tried to run the  solution  but it doesn't run  and can you provide comments  how  it is working please sir